# vue-router's router-link with actual refresh?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I'd like to my "SPA" refresh when I click a link, instead of its default behavior where you see the minimal component replacement.

It sounds like I'm killing the best part of SPA, but I feel that the links without refresh cause more troubles than benefits - the worst one I suppose is that the page doesn't apparently respond if you click a link to the current page, which is rather confusing in my opinion:

```
<!-- You click, then of course nothing happens when you're at HelloWorld -->
<router-link :to="{name: 'HelloWorld'}">link</router-link>
```

Comment: Yes, you are killing the very purpose of SPA. spa router like vue-router is designed for navigation which doesn't involve an actual page refresh. If your application is not working properly after navigation from one page to the other, then there is something wrong with your implementation that needs fixing.

Comment: @JulianPaoloDayag Thanks, that might make sense, but as I described in my question, the biggest frustration is that there's nothing happens when you click the link to the current page - the behavior make (at least) me think that the link is not responding because the link/website is broken.

Comment: can you give us a sample code that we can examine?

Comment: @JulianPaoloDayag I've added a sample.

Comment: Can you also provide your routes?

Comment: @JulianPaoloDayag `{ path: '/', name: 'HelloWorld', component: HelloWorld }`, which is the vue-cli 2.x default.

Comment: Wait. What you are trying to do is when a user clicks a link to the current page, you are expecting that the page will be re-rendered?

Comment: @JulianPaoloDayag Exactly. Isn't it how the most websites work?

Comment: If you are currently in the target page, vue-router will not re-render the current page as you already are in the target page. What reason do you have for wanting to refresh the page?

Comment: You can actually use the ‘mounted()’ hook to reset any variables you have.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177578/discussion-between-akai-and-julian-paolo-dayag).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Okay, I didn't know that a normal `<a>` tag works as my expectation *if history mode is used*, so I ended up doing this:

```
<a :href="$router.resolve({name: 'HelloWorld'}).href">link</a>
```

or maybe just:

```
<a href="/">link</a>
```

Comment: Thanks. I had router-link with :to object but I wanted a page reload in this one specific case so I did `$router.resolve(to).href`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The most problematic component in VueJS is the router in my experience, especially in history mode (and the community doesn't like it when I say that). Since I reworked the whole application and get rid of router-magic, replaced by <a> tags, everything works smoothly and reliable again. Router sometimes only changes the URL but is not reloading the page. 2 of 5 clicks on the very same components can cause this issue. Thats why I prefer always <a> over router-link components

Answer (score 3):

Thanks akai, I use your help in the case when I want to use the same component. I have a list of categories and when I click on a certain category page needs to be reloaded.

```
<a :href="$router.resolve({name:'category', params: {id: category.id}}).href">
    {{category.name}}
    <span>({{category.posts.length}})</span>
</a>
```

Comment: you cannot add params using this approach. Does this work for you?